# How many ways to do n chose k such that the picks are non-decreasing?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

Given n that represents the maximum value of all the numbers we can pick from such that

```
1 <= pick <= n
```

Given k that represents how many numbers we must pick.

I am interested in finding the number of combinations that will have a non-decreasing order.

For example with n = 10, k = 2 if we write it down we can observe:

```
Pick#1 Pick#2    
10     10 (only possible value)    
9      9 or 10 (same...)
8      8 -> 10    
.      .
.      .
1      1 -> 10 (all values are possible)
```

And so we find that for k = 2 the number of such combinations will be n(n+1)/2 = 55.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot derive a general formula that would work for any k.

My best attempt:

If n = 10, k = 3:

If Pick#1 = 1, we get (n+1)/2 = 55 combinations possible.

If Pick#1 = 2, we get (n(n+1)/2) - n combinations.

If Pick#1 = 3, we get (n(n+1)/2) - n - (n - 1) combinations.

If Pick#1 = 4, we get (n(n+1)/2) - n - (n - 1) - (n - 2) combinations.

.....

Which can sum to give a total of:

```
n * (n(n+1)/2) - n(n+1)/2 = (n-1) * (n(n+1)/2) combinations.
```

I attempt to generalize by recognizing that this pattern will repeat and by writing:

```
((n-1)^k-2) * (n(n+1)/2) total combinations.
```

But this is wrong as my test case is that n = 93, k = 8 should equal: 186087894300.

```
Pick#1  Pick#2 Pick#3    
1       10     10 
        9      9 or 10
        8      8 -> 10    
        .      .
        .      .
        1      1 -> 10

2       10     10 
        9      9 or 10
        8      8 -> 10    
        .      .
        .      .
        2      2 -> 10

3       10     10 
        9      9 or 10
        8      8 -> 10    
        .      .
        .      .
        3      3 -> 10
```

Thanking you in advance for any help!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find the number of non-decreasing sequences of length $k$ using $n$ symbols (numbers)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Exactly, also the numbers can repeat. And now that I think about it, I would also be curious as to the solution in the case of the numbers not allowed to repeat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the number of non-decreasing $k$-tuples of integers chosen from the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Let $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_k\rangle$ be such a $k$-tuple. Let $d_0=a_1-1$ and $d_k=n-a_k$, and for $i=1,\ldots,k-1$ let $d_i=a_{i+1}-a_i$. Note that the $(k+1)$-tuple $\langle d_0,\ldots,d_k\rangle$ is uniquely determined by $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_k\rangle$ **and vice versa**: from $\langle d_0,\ldots,d_k\rangle$ you can reconstruct $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_k\rangle$. What $(k+1)$-tuples $\langle d_0,\ldots,d_k\rangle$ are possible? Clearly each $d_i$ is a non-negative integer, and

$$\sum_{i=0}^kd_i=(a_1-1)+\sum_{k=1}^{k-1}(a_{i+1}-a_i)+(n-a_k)=n-1\;.$$

You can check that any $(k+1)$-tuple $\langle d_0,\ldots,d_k\rangle$ of non-negative integers summing to $n-1$ comes from a non-decreasing $k$-tuple $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_k\rangle$ whose terms are chosen from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Thus, there are exactly as many of your $k$-tuples as there are solutions in non-negative integers to the equation

$$x_0+x_1+\ldots+x_k=n-1\;.$$

This is a standard [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problem whose solution is

$$\binom{(n-1)+(k+1)-1}{(k+1)-1}=\binom{n+k-1}k=\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}\;;$$

the linked article gives a reasonably clear derivation of this formula.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer but C(93 + 8, 93) = 202095455100 != 186087894300.

Comment: This problem is from a training set of programming problems available on topcoder and it has been solved successfully by other users before.

Comment: @user2441988: Yes, I see the problem now: $d_0$ can’t be $0$, which introduces a slight distortion. I’ll fix it in a few minutes.

Comment: @user2441988: Fixed now, and it passes the test case.

Comment: Thank you for your help, any chances you might point out the first wrong thing I did in my attempt?

Comment: @user2441988: You’re welcome. I’d have to look a bit closer to be sure, but I’m pretty sure that you summed the $n=10,k=3$ cases incorrectly, and that would of course have thrown off any attempt to generalize.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to look at it more closely.

Comment: I'm ashamed to say it took me all this time to figure out the answer to the same problem with no duplicates is simply C(n, k).

Comment: @user2441988: Oops! My apologies: I meant to mention that that case is also covered in the WP article to which I linked.